# How to get value in directive from outside in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aU5aNw9L9AX5ptwGhsdr?p=preview).

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <h1>selectable</h1>
    <selectable text="link1" status="true"></selectable>
    <selectable text="link2" status="false"></selectable>
    <p>
      link1 is <!--status of link1, true or false-->
    </p>
    <p>
      link2 is <!--status of link2, true or false-->
    </p>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("app", [])
.directive("selectable", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      status: "=",
      text: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, ele, attr){
      ele.on("click", function(){
        scope.status = !scope.status;
        scope.$apply();
      });
    },
    templateUrl: "./tmpl.html"
  }
})
```

template:

```
<span class='myLink' ng-class='{"active": status, "": !status}'>
  {{text}}
  {{status}}
</span>
```

How can I get the status of link1 and link2 then show them up?

Thanks!

Comment: you can simply use ng-show

Comment: How can I get the status of link1 and link2 then show them up? ..your sending status as  true or false from your view to your isolated scope directive, where you want get them ? , please explain or elaborate what u want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

use a `ng-controller` directive

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

inside `MainCtrl` function define a two variables to represent status of the two links as,

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.link_1_status = true;
    $scope.link_2_status = false;
})
```

bind these two variables to `status` variable of the directive scope

```
<selectable text="link1" status="link_1_status"></selectable>
<selectable text="link2" status="link_2_status"></selectable>
```

and print the status as,

```
<p>
    link1 is {{link1Bool}}
</p>
<p>
    link2 is {{link2Bool}}
</p>
```

here is the [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/bK8jkqMQj3FVZJbQFa4d?p=preview)

**OR** if you prefer not to use `ng-controller` then use `ng-init`

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-init="link_1_status = true; link_2_status = false">
....
    <selectable text="link1" status="link_1_status"></selectable>
    <selectable text="link2" status="link_2_status"></selectable>    
....
</body>
```

here is the [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/u3rsbsAnpPCzHJyg7SoE?p=preview)

**WHY**

If you using like `<selectable text="link1" status="true"></selectable>` then you assign the `true` to the directive scope `status` variable, when you click it will toggle the value but you can't access that value because you don't have any reference to that value *(you just pass a raw value without a reference or identifire)*, so you need a reference to access that variable that's why we need something `link_1_status` & `link_2_status` to get access to the property.

Answer (score 0):

You need have that value inside some scope variable and pass it to directive `attribute` as you already using `=`(two way binding) angular will show magic of binding. If the value passed to isolated directive will get change then it will change the underlying `scope` value from where it passed & vice versa.

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <h1>selectable</h1>
    <selectable text="link1" status="link1Bool"></selectable>
    <selectable text="link2" status="link2Bool"></selectable>
    <p>
      link1 is {{link1Bool}}
    </p>
    <p>
      link2 is {{link2Bool}}
    </p>
</body>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/faLCbNQ0jA1mAGBGlOT4?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rqNrRXLy2FL2VVyF75p5?p=preview).

I think the proper way is to have a controller, and use him to share data between you form and add some logic to handle the data.

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<h1>selectable</h1>
<selectable text="link1" status="firstStatus"></selectable>
<selectable text="link2" status="secondStatus"></selectable>
<p>
  link1 is {{firstStatus}}
</p>
<p>
  link2 is {{secondStatus}}
</p>
</body>
```

and the basic controller code:

```
.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.firstStatus = true;
  $scope.secondStatus = false;
})
```